# Is there a standard for what to return for the base path (an empty path) in OpenAPI?

Tags: rest, openapi

I've tried searching around for the answer and cannot find anything. Perhaps I'm using the wrong terminology, and so apologies if this has already been asked and answered.

My question is whether OpenAPI specifies a standard for what to return for an empty path? i.e. if I had the following endpoints declared:

```
https://api.example.com/v1/users
https://api.example.com/v1/organizations
```

What should be returned if someone accesses

```
https://api.example.com/v1/
```

From what I could deduce, it's often either a 404 or it redirects to one of the implemented endpoints, but I couldn't find anything concrete.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard and it's not so bad. It is a place where we could make a wise design decision.

Of course there is simple solution: return 404 status code and empty body. It works quite well and you could be sure your consumers will understand that response.

But wouldn't it be better for example?

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

{
    "error": {
        "message": "Unrecognized request URL (GET: /). Please see docs at https://docs.example.com/.",
        "type": "invalid_request_error"
    }
}
```

> I think people often tend to underestimate the value of protocols being easy to debug/play with. It doesn't matter much in theory, but it matters a lot in practice. *Patrick Collison.*

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any standards or conventions on what to return for an API base path, which probably explains why you aren't finding much in response to your searches. If it's not a documented endpoint, then I'd expected it to return a 404. However if you wanted to sneakily return some useful links, such as to the documentation for the API, I'm sure that would also be fine!